# Image from database doesn't display in a django template even though the image is available when right-clicked "save as"

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm on development server and I'm trying to display an image in a template uploaded by user.

The image doesn't display even though it seems available to be saved. When I right-click "Save as", file name pops up in the window.

When I try to save the file to the hard drive it gives an error though.

I checked the media folder and it seems models work fine - pictures were uploaded to the media folder as intended. Also, I'm able to retrieve other data from database(chars, integers) - I only struggle with pictures.

I have revived all questions related to image upload available on stackexchange, and made lots of small changes to my code - but nothing seems to help me.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Lesson(models.Model):
    phrase = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    progress_bar = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    lesson_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.phrase

 class Lesson_Options(models.Model):
     lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
     option1_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
     option1_voice =   models.FilePathField(path="/media/user123/Elements/Projects/PENCIL/lesson/voice/", recursive=True)
     option1_photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, lesson_id):
le_objects = Lesson.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
me_options = Lesson_Options.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
lesson = le_objects.progress_bar
display_test = me_options.option1_photo
return render(request, 'lesson/detail.html', {'lesson': lesson, 'display_test':   display_test})
```

urls.py (Project urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^lesson/', include('lesson.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

urls.py (Application urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from lesson import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /lesson/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /lesson/5/
    url(r'^(?P<lesson_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /lesson/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<lesson_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/user123/Elements/Projects/PENCIL/lesson/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

detail.html

```
<li class="span4"> <a class="thumbnail"> <img alt="hello"
src="{{ display_test }}" height="300" width="300" class="option1" id="incorrect_answer1"></a> </li>
```

HTML Output

```
<img alt="hello" src="images/girl_1.jpg" height="300" width="300" class="option1" id="incorrect_answer1">
```

Comment: What is the output HTML?

Comment: Please update the question, and not post it on comment

Comment: Have you tried adding [this](http://pastebin.com/5KxAFpyH) to your ```urls.py```?

Comment: I've just tried. Doesn't help. I was also wondering... Does it matter where my media folder is in relation to template folder? I think in Django it doesn't matter - but I just have this feeling(coming from HTML) that maybe the problem is that Django doesn't find the image file. In HTML you source images from "images" folder in relation to index.html file.

Comment: what error is reported in browser console? is 403 or 404? also in the template your image doesn't appear to be served from the media folder. I think you need to post the "Lesson_Options" model in you question to figure what happens there.

Comment: i got 404 error in the console:  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: are the files in that folder on your server or are they missing?

Comment: I realized what was the problem was. 1. urls.py was missing code mentioned by @kroolik 2. I added this code but to the wrong urls.py.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer for future googlers. you'll also earn a badge for this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project urls.py file is missing:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

CORRECT CODE:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Lesson(models.Model):
    phrase = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    progress_bar = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    lesson_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.phrase

 class Lesson_Options(models.Model):
     lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson)
     option1_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
     option1_voice =   models.FilePathField(path="/media/user123/Elements/Projects/PENCIL/lesson/voice/", recursive=True)
     option1_photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, lesson_id):
le_objects = Lesson.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
me_options = Lesson_Options.objects.get(pk=lesson_id)
lesson = le_objects.progress_bar
display_test = me_options.option1_photo
return render(request, 'lesson/detail.html', {'lesson': lesson, 'display_test':   display_test})
```

urls.py (Project urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^lesson/', include('lesson.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        '',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

urls.py (Application urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from lesson import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /lesson/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /lesson/5/
    url(r'^(?P<lesson_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /lesson/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<lesson_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/user123/Elements/Projects/PENCIL/lesson/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

detail.html

```
<li class="span4"> <a class="thumbnail"> <img alt="hello"
src="{{ display_test }}" height="300" width="300" class="option1" id="incorrect_answer1"></a> </li>
```

HTML Output

```
<img alt="hello" src="images/girl_1.jpg" height="300" width="300" class="option1" id="incorrect_answer1">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [documentation for FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage). It seems you've done the first two steps properly. Try to follow step three. Instead of `display_test = me_options.option1_photo` put:

```
display_test = me_options.option1_photo.url
```

or try directly in the template:

```
<img alt="hello" src="{{ display_test.url }}" height="300" width="300" class="option1" id="incorrect_answer1">
```